# i am learning to create api but only reponse with id 1 is getting send others showing 404 error

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am learning to create api but only reponse with id 1 is getting send others showing 404 error. iam having users array with till id 8

```js
const express = require('express')
const Joi = require('joi')
const app = express()

const users = require('./users')

app.get('/users', (req , res) => {
    res.send(users)
})
app.get('/users/:id', (req , res) => {
    for(let i=0; i<users.length; i++){
        if(users[i].id !== parseInt(req.params.id)){
            res.status(404).send('name with given id not found')
        }else{
            res.send(users[i])
        }
    }
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? `.send()` submits the response for the request. That's like a "return" for the response. If `req.params.id` is the id of the first user in `users` you send that user as response. If the first user has not the id from the request you send the string `"...not found"` with status 404.